# Custom OAuth2 /oauth/authorize Endpoint

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to really keep my RESTful backend blissfully ignorant of all things HTML.  I would like it to only speak JSON to and from my HTML/CSS/JS front end and other connecting clients.  OAuth2 provides the `AuthorizationEndpoint` which services /oauth/authorize.  In its default behavior, the user approval page is intended to be a ModelAndView generated HTML result.

I would rather that my HTML/CSS/JS front end handled the display of the confirmation page (and potentially the login) and then POSTed the user's approval to /oauth/authorize.  The result from POSTing /oauth/authorize would be a JSON result containing the token and a URL to redirect to.  The front-end code would then handle the browser redirection back to the client.  The rest of the process would proceed as normal.

Am I thinking about this wrong?  Are there any security concerns that I may not be taking into consideration?

Thanks!

Comment: In implementing this, I find that I'm duplicating a lot of the `AuthorizationEndpoint` code.  While I'd love to subclass the `AuthorizationEndpoint` class, it looks like the `AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer` hardcodes the reference to the `AuthorizationEndpoint`.  Being able to hook into that `authorizationEndpoint()` and change the class that is created would make this endeavor much easier.  Is there a mechanism I'm not seeing to do this?

Comment: Seems like the shortest path to making a task like this straightforward would be to ask the `AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer` to provide an `AuthorizationEndpoint`.  This way I could provide my own implementation and still hook in to all the existing machinery.  Right now I'm in a world of copy/paste.

Comment: Given that I can't yet provide an `AuthorizationEndpoint` replacement to `AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer`, I just want to expose the configured objects (TokenGranter, ClientDetailsService, AuthorizationCodeServices, OAuth2RequestFactory, OAuth2RequestValidator, and UserApprovalHandler) as beans.  If I can expose them as beans, then I can allow the framework to `@Autowire` them into my replacement `AuthorizationEndpoint`.  Any thoughts out there on this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going in the wrong direction. `Login` and `Approval` page must be provided by authorization server and using standards of HTTP (eg: redirection using Location header).

If you want to DIY any thing, recommend grant type is `Resource Owner Password`. But it may not suitable for an pure client-side web application. Because it cannot (or hard) keep `secret key` secure!

I also have an application similar your, wrote with AngularJS and using `implicit` flow. My app completely using RESTful to talk with server. Except login/authorize the app, it's done by another web app (Spring MVC - default as Sparkl) at different domain.

Comment: Why must it be provided by the auth server though?  I didn't read that in the spec and it seems like a perversion of my beautiful REST/JSON server.

I'll post the solution I came up with for this once I make sure it's working as I expect.  But it uses the pathMapping() to change the "oauth/confirm_access" into "redirect:(url)".  I think this is the solution I was looking for after all.

Comment: Because the only `trusted client` can accept the credentials of the user and use it to exchange for `access token`. How can you prove your app is trusted without an `client_secret`?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I had a similar issue, I do auth on a client postback page and then only later on do I kick the user into the SPA - so because the user is already auth'd I just want a way of converting their cookie into a token. I ended up writing something like this which basically bypasses most of the oauth stuff. My thinking is that it'll only work if the user has a valid .NET auth cookie in the request, so it must be at least equally as secure as that, right?

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult GetToken()
    {
        if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            Response.StatusCode = 403;
            return Json(new {message = "Forbidden - user not logged in."}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        var claims = new ClaimsPrincipal(User).Claims.ToArray();
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Bearer");
        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(identity);
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, new AuthenticationProperties());
        var token = Startup.OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket);
        return Json(new { token }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```